# Why does mercurial report back incomplete name of tag when this name contains dashes?

Tags: mercurial

I noticed Mercurial does not report back complete tag's name it was given as argument to `update` command in case the tag does not exist and contains dashes in its name. Is there any logical reason for this?

```
$ hg init test_repo && cd test_repo && hg up 'some-tag-with-dashes'
abort: unknown revision 'some'!
```

Mercurial version 2.9.2

I raised this issue at https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4339

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", there's a logical reason to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a little quirky. What's happening is first hg looks up your string as a tag, then a branch name, then it parses it as a [revset](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revset). The revset parses fine, but then it looks for a tag named "some" so it can do set arithmetic on it, and then it fails that way.

We should probably be able to do better though, and I'll update the [bug](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4339) that was filed about this with my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, it seems the error is happening only when your `some-tag-with-dashes` **does not exists**. The error messages could clearly be improved, but it is working as intended :

```
$ hg init
$ touch file; hg add file; hg commit -m "add file"

$ hg tag some-tag-with-dashes
$ hg up some-tag-with-dashes
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved

$ hg up some-other-tag-with-dashes
abort: unknown revision 'some'!
```

Does your tag appears when you do a `hg tags` :

```
$ hg tags 
tip                                1:00acd65cf970
some-tag-with-dashes               0:8a895a220fa5
```

Comment: *I just checked, it seems the error is happening only when your some-tag-with-dashes does not exists.* That's what I stated in my question. *The error messages could clearly be improved, but it is working as intended*. I know it works but the question is specifically about misleading report.